# Recently Viewed Products Items not updating for logged user

Tags: magento2, recently-viewed

I have issues for logged in user only, if not logged in then updating properly.

My code on: `Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="page.bottom.container">
            <block class="Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed" after="-" name="recently_viewed" cacheable="false" template="Magento_Reports::widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
```

Please help me

Comment: which issue you are facing here?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Recently Viewed Products Items not updating for logged user